# PowerShell bulk replacing a specific character and rename file extension

Tags: powershell, file-rename, bulk, batch-rename

I need to bulk rename files in a file share that

1. contain a specific character, namely a tilde `~` and
2. have the file extension in capital letters or none at all.

The goal would be to replace the tilde with a simple `-`, keep the file extension, if there is one, but transform it into lowercase letters.

I've had success with the first part of the script that finds the files

```cs
$PATH = "\\<Fileservername>\<Folder>\"
$pattern = "*~*"
Get-ChildItem $PATH -Recurse | where {$_.Name -like $pattern}
```

What I'm struggling with is the second part of the script the renaming.
I've found two topics here:

- [Powershell renaming a specific Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019236/powershell-renaming-a-specific-character)
- [PowerShell Regex Bulk Replace Filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394169/powershell-regex-bulk-replace-filenames)

I haven't been able to adapt those solutions to my need plus there may be additional steps to take in order to convert the given file name from capital letters to lowercase letters or skip this if the file has no file extension.

An example would be to rename `ACUJLH~H` to `ACUJLH-H` and `KYA3BM~Q.PDF` to `KYA3BM-Q.pdf`.

Comment: Please *show* your attempt at adopting the two linked topics, so that we can help you fix it. The first linked post in particular looks like it should be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my contribution. I have added the `-File` switch to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet so it will look for files only and will not try and handle directory names.
Also, I have changed the replace pattern to `~+` so files that have repeating tildes will be replaced with a single `-` character. (`KYA3BM~~~~Q.PDF` becomes `KYA3BM-Q.pdf`)

```
$path = "D:\Code\PowerShell\StackOverflow"
$pattern = "*~*"
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$_.Name -like $pattern} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $directory = $_.DirectoryName                # or [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_.FullName)  or use Split-Path $_.FullName -Parent
        $filename  = $_.BaseName -replace '~+', '-'  # or [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name) -replace '~+', '-'
        $extension = $_.Extension                    # or [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name)
        if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($extension)) { $filename += $extension.ToLower() }
        $newname = Join-Path -Path $directory -ChildPath $filename
        Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $newName -Force
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to filter files those meets your criteria. Then using `ForEach-Object` compare for extensions and build new file names for every found item. Finally, using `Rename-Item` cmdlet you make the change.

```
$PATH = '\\<Fileservername>\<Folder>\'    
Get-ChildItem $PATH -Recurse -Include '*~*' | ForEach-Object {
        [String]$Extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_)
        [String]$NewFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name) -replace '~','-'
        if ($Extension){ $NewFileName += $Extension.ToLower() }
        Rename-Item $_.FullName $(Join-Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_)) $NewFileName) -Force
    }
```